# How to compare previous value with current value before saving it to database?

Tags: android, database, firebase

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrkXc.png)I'm making an IoT app in which I'm showing the value of sensors using real-time database and saving it to the datbase class.

But I don't want any two consecutive values to be same.

How can I compare the previous value with current value before saving it to the databse classes.

```
confirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Get your custom_toast.xml layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

    //Initializing the text views
    EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.link2);
    final String link2 = editText.getText().toString();

    EditText editText1 =  findViewById(R.id.idvalue);
    final String StringValue = editText1.getText().toString();


    //Adding functionality to the text views
    fire2 = new Firebase("https://iot.firebaseio.com/");
    Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2+"/S1");
    fireChild.setValue("7");

    // Read from the database
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            if(StringValue.length()>0 && link2.length()>0) {
                try {
                status = dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog2").getValue().toString();}
                catch (NullPointerException ignored){}

                if(status==null){
                    TextView text4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                    text4.setText(" Error: Wrong ID. ");
                    // Toast...
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 540);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setView(layout);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);
                    pin.setText(status);
                    String status2=status;
                    mDatabaseHelper.addData("Date: " + Date + "   Value: "+status);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            // Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the current and previous value in your code?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 
dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog2").getValue().toString();
analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);
I want to compare last value of "analogvalue " with the next value of "analogvalue ".

Comment: What is the problem right now? Cannot compare?

Comment: @Ticherhaz Yes. I'm not sure how to do that.
The code I previously wrote was not working.
Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @user10851894 First of all, you get the value from the input. After that, you get the value from Firebase. Lastly, compare between both of them.

Comment: @Ticherhaz Their is no input. I want to compare the values from firebase itself.
The previous value and current value from firebase.

Comment: @user10851894so what is `StringValue` for?

Comment: @Ticherhaz 

dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog2").getValue().toString(); 
This line is fetching the data from the firebase node.

analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);
And this line is storing the value of firebase in "analogvalue" variable.

Now I want to compare the previous and current value of the "analogvalue" variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202459/discussion-between-ticherhaz-and-user10851894). @user10851894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trials and error, I found a solution to this problem.
First of all, save the value coming from the database then define an array of length 2 and save the value from the database to the 1 index of the array then swap the values of the array and then compare the values of an array for example:

```
status = dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog2").getValue().toString();}
val1 = [prev,curr]

val1[1] = status
val1[1],val1[0] = val1[0],val1[1]

if val1[0]!=val1[1]:
  //Do something
```

This will work when the value at particular node changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may store two values in the reference:

prevVal and currentVal, e.g.:

```
Object:
 {
    "value": currentVal,
    "prev_value": prevVal
 }

ref.setValue(value: „x”);
```

then when in addValueListener:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              previousValue = snapshot.val().prevVal;
              newValue = snapshot.val().value;

                //then compare -> e.g. compareShomehow(previousVal, newVal)
                //then save to db
                //then update previousValue -> ref.setValue(prev_value:newValue);


 }
```

Comment: dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog2").getValue().toString(); analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status); I want to compare last value of "analogvalue " with the next value of "analogvalue ".
mDatabaseHelper class is not communicating with firebase it is saving the values coming from firebase to the databse.